# Is it possible to generate an alternate structure for multi-tag urls?

Tags: url-rewriting, tags

I know that one can query multiple tags with the + syntax, as in www.example.com?tag=?test+test2+test3

I'm looking for a solution where the URL would be in this format instead: www.example.com/foo/test/test2/test3

Can anyone give any tips how best to arrive at this solution?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to pull something together using:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule

I PITA would be having to create any intra-site links manually. Once you have a URI you can pretty much parse it out to query whatever you want.